# Stopwatch jQuery, calculate average and display

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, time, average

I am working on a stopwatch and for now it works, but I want that I can calculate the average of time people get. E.g. let's say I have 5 times in an `array` which looks like the following: `scores = ["00:32:192", "00:30:126", "00:31:542", "00:25:236", "00:36:320"];`. You may think now: *What the hell is it?* Well the times are in: **minutes:seconds:milliseconds**. The array is printed to the screen by using a `for` loop.

**jQuery**

```
var int,
     ms=0,
     s=0,
     m=0;

$('#swatch').text("00:00:00");

function swatch(){

  var startTime = new Date().getTime();
  int = setInterval(function(){
      var time = new Date().getTime();
      var dif = time-startTime;
      ms= dif%1000;
      s = Math.floor(dif/1000)%60;
      m = Math.floor(dif/1000/60)%60;

        if(ms < 10) {
            ms = '0'+ms;
        }

        if(s < 10) {
            s = '0'+s;
        }

        if(m < 10) {
            m = '0'+m;
        }

        $('#swatch').text(m+':'+s+':'+ ms);

  },1);

}

var scores= [];



$(document).on('keydown', function(e){
    var result = $('#swatch').text();
    var i = parseInt(scores.length);

    if(e.keyCode == 32 && !int){
        swatch();

    } else if (e.keyCode == 32){
        clearInterval(int);
        int=0;

        scores.push(result);
        $('#score ol').append('<li>' + scores[i] + '</li>');

        if(scores.length >= 5) {
            $('#ao5').html("ao5: 00:27:43");
            $('#ao5').slideDown(500);
        }
        if (scores.length >= 12) {
            $('#ao12').html("ao12: 00:27:43");
            $('#ao12').slideDown(500);
        }
    }

});
```

In my code above this, you see this:

```
if(scores.length >= 5) {
    $('#ao5').html("ao5: 00:27:43");
    $('#ao5').slideDown(500);
}
if (scores.length >= 12) {
    $('#ao12').html("ao12: 00:27:43");
    $('#ao12').slideDown(500);
}
```

I want if the array has 5 different time values *(as in the example above where I showed you the array format)* it outputs the average on the screen. As you see I just filled it in for myself to picture it, but I want a function that calculates it. I am building this in jQuery because the timer worked better in here than in JS.

If some of you guys could give me an example and **re-write** my code with the function in it, that'd be great. I am really struggling with this for days to figure out how I can calculate an average of 5 and/or 12.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the code I provide below doesn't rely on JQuery or any library directly. You feed it an array of 'time-strings', and it gives you back an average. You can use whatever library you choose to get that array of strings.

First, you need a utility function which breaks a time-string into it's component pieces:

```
var str_to_time = function(time_str) {
  var pieces =time_str.split(':');
  return {
    minutes: parseInt(pieces[0], 10),
    seconds: parseInt(pieces[1], 10),
    milliseconds: parseInt(pieces[2], 10)
  };
};
```

Now a function to convert an array of time-strings to an array of times:

```
var str_array_to_time_array = function(str_array) {
  return str_array.map(str_to_time);
};
```

Lastly, a way to average all these values together:

```
var average_time = function(time_array) {
  var minutes = 0;
  var seconds = 0;
  var milliseconds = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < time_array.length; i++) {
    minutes += time_array[i].minutes;
    seconds += time_array[i].seconds;
    milliseconds += time_array[i].milliseconds;
  }

  minutes /= time_array.length;
  seconds /= time_array.length;
  milliseconds /= time_array.length;

  // Minutes and seconds may be fractional. Carry the fractions down.
  seconds += (minutes - Math.floor(minutes)) * 60;
  minutes = Math.floor(minutes);
  milliseconds += (seconds - Math.floor(seconds)) * 1000;
  seconds = Math.floor(seconds);
  milliseconds = Math.round(milliseconds);
  // if milliseconds is >= 1000, add a second.
  seconds += Math.floor(milliseconds / 1000);
  milliseconds %= 1000;
  // If seconds >= 60, add a minute.
  minutes += Math.floor(seconds / 60); 
  seconds %= 60;

  return {
    minutes: minutes,
    seconds: seconds,
    milliseconds: milliseconds
  };
};
```

Now you can call something like the following to get an average:

```
average_time(str_array_to_time_array(['33:23:354', '34:00:32']))
// Object {minutes: 33, seconds: 41, milliseconds: 693}
```

Comment: ahh thanks for the patient and for the time you took to write this. It works now. Had to figure out your code, but I nailed it. Thanks